# Doctrine2 Relation with 3 entities

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, relation

I have 3 entities:
User
Role
Company

Typically one User has one Role and many Companies.
I have set up this successfully.

But how would I set up the relations if a User has a Role depending on the Company?
I tried it with an additional entity UserCompanyRole.

In User:

```
/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserCompanyRole", mappedBy="user")*/
protected $userCompanyRoles;
public function getUserCompanyRoles() {
    return $this->userCompanyRoles;
}
public function addUserCompanyRole(UserCompanyRole $userCompanyRole) {
    $this->userCompanyRoles[] = $userCompanyRole;
}
```

Same in Role and Company

In UserCompanyRole:

```
/** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userCompanyRoles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(  onDelete = "CASCADE" )
 */
private $user;
public function getUser() {
    return $this->user;
}
public function setUser(User $user = null) {
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

Same functions for Role and Company.

This will get complicated when creating queries.
Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If a user can have multiple roles and companies I would say yes. Bit in a company a role has multiple employees. So I would make it companyRole.